# How to override Alfresco tomcat files in eclipse project

Tags: alfresco

I'm new to Alfresco and I'm trying to override in my eclipse project messages files located in tomcat alfresco (not share) at C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages

I've tried to put them under alfresco/extension/messages and alfresco/web-extension/messages but both didn't work.

Does anybody have an idea.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

try tomcat/shared/classes/messages

Comment: Hi alfrescian... I need the location where to put these files in my eclipse project, not in tomcat

Comment: well, that depends on your build files...How do you deploy your files from eclipse to tomcat?

Comment: I use maven to deploy the WAR file

Comment: then use maven to copy your *.properties to tomcat/shared....
You could also try to describe your use case in detail - maybe override *.properties is not the best approach

Comment: Well, I want to change the label of certain fields in the advanced search form, namely modifier and creator. Also I tried in vain to override workflowModel.xml to mask one property in it. Overriding seems not to work alfresco-wise, although it works in share.

Comment: change label of a field in advanced search form in /alfresco, right?

Comment: afaik you can simply add a display-label-id to your advanced search form definition: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Advanced_Search_Custom_Attributes

Answer (score 0):

OK just in case somebody runs into this, it seems that I have forgotten to define the path of my files in the eclipse project in a bundle-context.xml file. Now it works.